# How to remove popView if we tap anywhere in the background except tapping in popView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, view, uigesturerecognizer, tap

I have created one popView with textfield and button in ViewController. if i click button then popView is appearing, and i am able to enter text in textfield and submit is working, and if i tap anywhere in view also i am able to remove popView, but here i want if i tap on anywhere in popView i don't want to dismiss popView, Please help me in the code.

here is my code:

```
 import UIKit

 class PopUPViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var popView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    popView.isHidden = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func butnAct(_ sender: Any) {
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
    popView.isHidden = false
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PopUPViewController.dismissView))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func dismissView() {
    self.popView.isHidden = true
    view?.backgroundColor = .white
}

@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.textLabel.text = inputField.text
}
}
```

In my code if i tap anywhere in the view popView is removing even if i tap on popView also its removing, i don't need that, if i tap on popView then popView need not to be remove.

Please help me in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `override` the **touchesBegan** method which is `triggered` when a `new touch` is `detected` in a `view` or `window`. By using this `method` you can check a specific `view` is touched or not.

Try like this

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     let touch = touches.first
     if touch?.view != self.popView {
        dismissView()
    }
}

func dismissView() {
    self.popView.isHidden = true
    view?.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the way I would have architected this, but to get around the problem you face you need to adapt your `dismissView` method so that it only dismisses the view if the tap is outside the popView.

To do this modify your selector to include the sender  (the `UITapGestureRecogniser` )as a parameter:

```
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PopUPViewController.dismissView(_:)))
```

and then in your function accept that parameter and test whether the tap is inside your view, and if so don't dismiss the view:

```
@objc func dismissView(_ sender: UITapGestureRegognizer) {
  let tapPoint = sender.location(in: self.popView)
  if self.popView.point(inside: tapPoint, with: nil)) == false {
    self.popView.isHidden = true
    view?.backgroundColor = .white
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Popup view is inside the parent view of viewcontroller that's why on tap  of popview also your popview is getting hidden.
So to avoid just add a view in background and name it bgView or anything what you want and replace it with view. And it will work fine .

Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bgView: UIView!//Add this new outlet
@IBOutlet weak var popView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    popView.isHidden = true

}



@IBAction func butnAct(_ sender: Any) {
    bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)//change view to bgView[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    popView.isHidden = false
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissView))
    bgView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)//change view to bgView
}

@objc func dismissView() {
    self.popView.isHidden = true
    bgView.backgroundColor = .white//change view to bgView
}

@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.textLabel.text = inputField.text
}
```

[image: screen shot of view]

Comment: thanks bro the first answer solved my issue.. but thank you for detailed answer